# scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do something like this.

http://www.mini.jp/event_campaign/big-point/

What I can't figure out is how to make the animation happen based on the scroll when the scroll hits a specific position. I have similar blocks of content that I only want to animate parts of it based on the scroll and when the block is within the browsers view area when scrolling.

I understand using the scroll event to get the scrollTop position I'm more concerned with how everything else would work.

```
$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
    var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
});
```

Anyone can help explain some of this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at their source? Quite interesting to be honest: http://www.mini.jp/event_campaign/big-point/commons/scripts/animate.js tip: press ctrl+u. (using developers tools on the original page looks better).

Comment: Thanks MiniGod after I posted I realized the code was not minified.

Answer (score 1):

Just like what [MiniGod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916892/minigod) said in the comment, look in to the source code ([animate.js](http://www.mini.jp/event_campaign/big-point/commons/scripts/animate.js)), and you can see that they have recorded all the "scenes" and all other things like `alpha` and `pos` for everything.

```
// scene 1
{
    scene:"#scene1",
    name:".car",
    runStatus:[
        {p:10,pos:true,x:275,y:240,alpha:true,opacity:1,scale:true,orgSize:[475,270],scaleSize:1},
        {p:180,pos:true,x:275,y:200,alpha:true,opacity:1,scale:true,orgSize:[475,270],scaleSize:1},
        {p:270,pos:true,x:275,y:140,alpha:true,opacity:1,scale:true,orgSize:[475,270],scaleSize:1},
        {p:500,pos:true,x:275,y:-300,alpha:true,opacity:0,scale:true,orgSize:[475,270],scaleSize:1}
        ]
}
```